# "$()" or `` is not properly expanding the linux command in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, command, echo, expansion

My code snippet has an echo line as below:

```
echo "$(wc -l prov_bulk) provisioning commands found between $t_stmp1 of $(head -1 file_list) till $t_stmp2 of $(tail -1 file_list)"
```

Expected output:

```
1054721 provisioning commands found between 2017033023 of 170330.AUG till 2017033102 of 170331.AUG
```

Output getting:

```
1054721 prov_bulk provisioning commands found between 2017033023 of 170330.AUG till 2017033102 of 170331.AUG
```

Why the file name "prov_bulk" also shows up ? How to get rid of this ?

Comment: Read the documentation for `wc`.

Comment: The filename is part of the output of your command. It expands perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply adding a `<` should solve your problem.  The redirection omits the filename.

```
echo "$(wc -l < prov_bulk) provisioning commands found between $t_stmp1 of $(head -1 file_list) till $t_stmp2 of $(tail -1 file_list)"
```